# C++ regex expression at index

Tags: c++, regex

Having a string sequence of 0 and 1, I need to create a regular expression that matches multiple substrings at multiple positions.

```
Example:
string sequence: "001100110111100010100101000011111010"
substring1: "1100"  position1: 2
substring2: "10"    position2: 3
substring3: "10001" position3: 12
```

Should return true or false if all substrings are matched at all given positions.

It is possible to write such a regular expression in c++?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use substr() function for each possible substring?

Comment: To improve performance, because I have multiple string sequence, and for each sequence I will have to iterate each time through the substring vector and I want to avoid this.

Comment: Well it's possible using lookaheads. Now tell us what you have tried ?

Comment: @georgiana_e In that case you can try a modified version of the KMP algorithm. Instead of 1 table, you can maintain tables for each of the possible substrings. Ofcourse you can also reduce the number of substrings by 1st checking if one substring dominates another.

Comment: I firstly want to know if there is a possibility to write c++ regex expression  in which I can say: I want to match this at that position.

Comment: if ( fullString.substr( position, mySubstring.size() ) == mySubstring ) {}

Comment: I want first to write the expressions for all the given substrings and positions, then itereate through the strings vector and find a match. I want first to write the expressions because I have different elements and for each element I want to write an expression. Actually my string looks like "Elem:010011".

Answer (score 0):

```
const char * sequence = "001100110111100010100101000011111010";       
boost::regex e("??1100??????10001");
bool all_present = boost::regex_match ( sequence, e );
```

**Second method:**

```
  const char * sequence = "001100110111100010100101000011111010";       
  boost::regex exp1("1100");
  boost::regex exp2("10");
  boost::regex exp3("10001");

  bool all_present = boost::regex_match ( sequence, sequence + 2, exp1) &&  
                     boost::regex_match ( sequence, sequence + 3, exp2) &&
                     boost::regex_match ( sequence, sequence + 12, exp3);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is regex ?

Comment: I can have up to 200 characters in my string. I can not put '?' 200 times.

Comment: I am confused with known locations 2, 3, 12?

Comment: Locations 2,3,12, represents the starting position. For example substring1: "1100"  position1: 2 means that I want to match "1100" starting at position 2 in the string.